# SSRS Visual Studio 2010 Report Server project template

Tags: visual-studio-2010, reporting-services

Where to download the SSRS (SQL Server Reporting Server) project template for Visual Studio 2010? I have downloaded Sql Server Data Tools (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/tools.aspx) and installed it, but I don't see the project template in VS 2010

[image]

Comment: any idea which component I should install?

Comment: no one here designed a crystal report in visual studio 2010?